# How to write SQL query based on complex conditions mentioned in DB2 Database

Tags: sql, database, db2

**Table name is : *RU_OUTPUT***

Data is :

```
id  rudef   value   jobid   st_dt   
-----------------------------------------------------
8   23      200     32      1481585920      
9   24      2       32      1481989201      
12  24      3       32      1481547920      
10  26      50      32      1481544560      
13  26      89      32      1481545920      
14  24      69      32      1481548920  
15  23      56      32      1486899920
16  29      896     32      1486789920
```

**Expected Result Summary:**
*firstly we have to find all the rudef having count more than 1,
after that for all those rudef we have to find the last and 2nd last record value as different column ONLY when lastvalue > secondlastvalue.*

> (last record will be assumed based on the id for that record i.e. for
>   rudef '24' the last record will be where id = 14 and the second last
>   where id = 12)

### Expected Result

```
rudef   lastvalue  secondlastvalue
24      69         3
26      89         50
```

> Note: Even though rudef '23' count is 2 but their lastvalue is 56 which is less than second last value 200, hence it will not be considered.

Comment: Do one thing at a time.  First, write a query that solves the count greater than one problem.  Then write the query for comparing values.  Finally, combine them.

Comment: There are 2 records for `rudef`=23. Why is it not in your expected output?

Comment: @Utsav I clearly mentioned in the note.

Comment: Ok. Correcting the answer

Comment: @Utsav one more thing the DB is DB2.

Comment: row_number over clause will work in both. For any other syntax error you should be able to fix it.

Comment: for `26` also, `13  26      50` which is last values as per id, the value `50` is less that  `10  26      89`  Then why do u expect this?

Comment: yeah you are write sorry for this, editing question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. But the logic with which you are rejecting `23`, with same logic `26` will also not be in expected output. Anyways you can tweak internal queries to get the expected output. I tried in Oracle and it is giving expected output.

```
SELECT *
FROM
  ( SELECT rudef,
           max(value) AS lastvalue,
           min(value) AS secondlastvalue
   FROM
     ( SELECT t.*,
              row_number() over (partition BY rudef
                                 ORDER BY value DESC) AS val_rank
      FROM
        ( SELECT r.*,
                 row_number() over (partition BY rudef
                                    ORDER BY id DESC) AS rnk
         FROM RU_OUTPUT r) t
      WHERE rnk <=2 ) s
   WHERE rnk=val_rank
   GROUP BY rudef)
WHERE lastvalue<>secondlastvalue
```

Output

```
+-------+-----------+-----------------+
| RUDEF | LASTVALUE | SECONDLASTVALUE |
+-------+-----------+-----------------+
|    24 |        69 |               3 |
|    26 |        89 |              50 |
+-------+-----------+-----------------+
```

Comment: great it worked as expected. Thanks for your time bro.
You are really smooth as far as SQL queries is concerned, and yeah it make sense  'No Votedown up to now'

Comment: just one more question if i add one more field **st_dt** in the *Select statement* after _min(value) AS secondlastvalue_.Then the result will change why it is so, please consider any column i am adding in select also added in group by clause.

Answer (score 3):

In most databases, you can use conditional aggregation and the ANSI standard `row_number()` function:

```
select rudef,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then value end) as last_value,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then value end) as second_last_value
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by rudef order by id desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by rudef
having max(case when seqnum = 1 then value end) > max(case when seqnum = 2 then value end);
```

This assumes that `id` can be used to determine the last value.  (Just change the `order by`s if another column should be used.)

I should note that you do not have to check for two values matching a `rudef`.  If there is only one match, then the `max()` expression will be `NULL` and fail the `having` clauses.

Answer (score 1):

Check below query working perfect for SQL server or Oracle.

```
        with CTE as
        (
        select * from (
        select * from (
        select *,row_number() over(partition by rudef order by r desc) as Rnk
        from
        ( select *,row_number() over(order by (select 1))  as R from RU_OUTPUT)an

        )a where Rnk < 3  )b  -- change 4 for find 3rd last
        pivot
        (
         max(value)for rnk in ([2],[1])
        )
        as s

        )
        select c1.rudef,max(c1.[1]) as 'lastvalue',
        max(c1.[2]) as 'secondlastvalue'  from CTE C1   
        group by c1.rudef
        having max(c1.[2]) is not null and max(c1.[1]) is not null
        and max(c1.[1]) > max(c1.[2])   -- here condtion is lastvalue > secondlastvalue you can change it also
        order by rudef
```

Using this query you can also calculate 3rd lastvalue and so on.

```
max(c1.[1]) = lastvalue
max(c1.[2]) = 2nd lastvalue
max(c1.[3]) = 3rd lastvalue 
   ............and so on
```

Let us know if you have any concerns.